# How can I know if two tabs share the same renderer process?

Tags: google-chrome

Despite sandboxing, two different tabs in Chrome can share the same renderer process, for example when they share the same JavaScript environment.

Given two Chrome tabs, how can I know if they share the same process?

Comment: Do you mean... progammatically? Visually? Through the UI? Through the task manager? Surely there is a way to distinguish at some level of the architecture, but you didn't specify what your expected user experience is. Are you writing a program or are you looking for something a (power) end-user can use?

Comment: I'm looking for something a power end-user can use, so visually, UI or task manager are all fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Chrome, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to open Chrome's task manager.

[image: Task manager]

Then, right click on the column headings in the task manager. Enable the "Process ID" column.

[image: Process ID check box]

Now, you can check the Process IDs next to each tab. If they are the same for two tabs, then the tabs are open in the same process.

[image: Process ID column]